# SwiftUI - VoiceOver - Double Tapping On Accessible element always triggers Button

Tags: swiftui, uiaccessibility

I have a button in HStack{}. I made HStack accessibleElement(), and added two accessible custom actions. When I run the app in VoiceOver Mode, I see customActions, but when I double tap on focussed area, which is HStack{}, Button() is always triggered. I can't figure out how to disable the double-tap on Button.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button("one){
                print("one selected")
            }.accessibilityHidden(true)
        }
        .accessibilityElement()
        .accessibilityAction(named: "Action One", {
            print("first actioned")
        })
        .accessibilityAction(named: "Action two", {
            print("Second actioned")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your full code ?

Comment: Yes, it is my full code. I just figured, there is a default accessibilityAction - ```.accessibilityAction {
            print("default action")
        }}```. This fixed the problem.